# Button in django template doesn't put data in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a app named "mysite". I want it to execute a python script,when button is clicked, that will put dummy data in database(add row) for now(originally i will be pulling data from a API) but nothing happens when button is clicked.

urls.py

```
path('', views.index),
```

views.py

```
from .fetch_data import get_data

def index(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST' and 'script' in request.POST):
        get_data()

    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html')
```

index.html in "mysite/templates/mysite" folder

```
<form method="POST" name='script'>
{% csrf_token %}    
<button type="submit" >Fetch data from source</button>
</form>
```

fetch_data.py

```
    from .models import Hosts
    import time, sys

    def get_data():
        print('here in function')
        p = Hosts(hostname="first data")
        p.save()
```

But when i click button, nothing happens. View should remain the same even after successful button click.

Note: fetch_data.py is on same folder as views.py and urls.py.

Comment: action attribute is missing in html form.

Comment: Oh,yeah. I have added action="." in form. it's not giving error but still not working.

Comment: Not adding row into database as opposed to what's written in fetch_data.py

Comment: getting any error in console ?

Comment: Just this "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 635"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name attribute in the form does not send anything to server as post data.
You should change the button like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="script">Fetch data from source</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be this will help you

```
from .fetch_data import get_data

def index(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        script = get_data.objects.all()
        script.save()

    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html')
```